# Writing in the Dust

Tags: cipher

As you continue down the corridor, you come across a door and panel, clearly left untouched for many years. Hoping to get lucky, you try the door but it is locked. On the panel is a line of 6 buttons, colored RED, ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE, and PURPLE. As you search, you notice writing in the dust. You can faintly make out what appears to be:

```
IPF S: GPIFV
       PIU
       PFD
       CR N
       PL F
       PUPI
```

How do you proceed?

Comment: Are we certain that this is pertinent to the "cipher" tag?  Regardless, a nice little puzzle.

Comment: @can-ned_food I see what you mean. If you know of a better tag, I'll switch it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Making this community wiki so maybe someone else can take it from here:

> The dust appears to contain the color names except for YELLOW, it contains BLUE twice, and I'm not sure what the word preceding the colon is.  "PRESS" perhaps? 
>  [image]

CreatedByBrett got the final bit:

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

Beastly Gerbil's answer covered everything except the meaning of the characters on the left. I think I got that and can answer the question.

> The characters in the dust are instructions to follow.  Some parts of the letters have been smudged out.  Filling them in, we get:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvCRH.png

Comment: Wasn't my answer

Comment: Oh, I hadn't seen "community wiki" before, and I saw your name, so I figured it was yours. Looks like it was ... Tilper!

Comment: @BrettFromLA, indeed, 'twas I!  Stack Exchange could definitely slightly improve the author indication for community wikis, but oh well.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, thanks, was struggling to get that image to stay hidden then had to give up because break time was over.  Sigh.

Comment: @tilper Limited break times, the bane of creativity.